# where should I put 'enough' in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. I'm not close enough to the person that I would prepare something for the person's birthday.
> 2. I'm not close to the person enough that I would prepare something for the person's birthday.

I feel #1. is right but I'm not sure. which one is the right one?

Comment: I'm not a close enough _friend_ that I would plan this person's birthday party.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first.  You want to indicate the *degree* of closeness (how close? Close enough.)

In the second rendering, "enough" could be misconstrued to mean *how often* you are *physically near* that person (are you close to her often? Not [often] enough that . . . "

Comment: Just a note of clarification: I agree that the first is better, but I wouldn't say that the second is grammatically wrong.